# Should I apply for more credit cards in order to improve my credit score?

Tags: credit-card, credit-score

Is it true that you can increase your score by applying for more cards? Do you need to be active on those cards for that to work?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not simply by applying for more cards, but rather by being approved for credit cards.  In fact, too many declined credit applications can hurt your credit score.

I'm not certain of the details, but some activity is also necessary.  Not using your lines of credit can be seen as a detrimental factor.  I assume they are trying to guard against being gamed.  So, having a bunch of unused lines of credit is not necessarily good.

Finally, having too many open lines of credit (for some definition of "too many") can also be a bad thing, though I'm not sure if this effects your credit score or is simply used as a reason by some issuers to decline your application.

Answer (score 2):

It would probably be more effective to call your existing credit card companies and have them raise your limit.

Ultimately, though. I'd suggest not trying to game the credit scoring system. Get extra cards if you need them, not to increase your score.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @George. I would also add that the amount of credit available to you has an impact on your credit score. There is a point where the credit bureaus will see you as having the ability to get yourself in trouble by using all the existing credit available to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have lines of credit, you won't have a very healthy mix for your credit score.  I don't know if that hurts you per se, but it is better to have different types.

Car loans, home loans, lines of credit and student loans I have seen written on a credit report as being a good mix.